# Optimize a code combining title of a list

Tags: r, list, combinations, paste

I do have a list `Factor.lst` composed of 16 elements. Each element of the list is a vector of characteres. I would like to obtain a new vector of size [1:16] composed by the combinaison of each charactere string. I manage to obtain what I want using this :

```
col.titles <- c(paste(Factor.lst[[1]], collapse=" "), (paste(Factor.lst[[2]], collapse=" ") ... (paste(Factor.lst[[16]], collapse=" ")))
```

But that's a lot of line to reach 16 ! How can I call the list directly instead of each element within the list ? I was thinking of something like this but that's not working.

```
col.titles <- c(paste(Factor.lst[[1:16]], collapse=" "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` will apply a function to each element of an object, so you can use it to apply `paste(x, collapse=' ')` to each element of `Factor.lst`.

Try:

```
sapply(Factor.lst, paste, collapse=' ')
```

Comment: There is a lot of function that I still need to learn ;) Thanks you that's perfect